# Excel - External Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some external trading system that creates a formula in excel to show real time stocks, options and strikes. I was trying for few days to link this formula to others cells, but so far unsuccessful.

Cell A1: BBDCC36

Cell B1: =BC|COT!BBDCC36.PEX

What i need:

B1 to be like: `=BC|COT!&A1&.PEX`

I need some reference to a cell, but i couldnt do it. There is any trick to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you are lacking are the `"`s around the text elements:

```
="BC|COT!"&A1&".PEX"
```